# EXT JS 2.3; Internet Explorer 8; GridPanel Records Wrap, but Shouldn't

Tags: javascript, extjs, internet-explorer-8

I'm using EXT JS 2.3 and looking at an issue that occurs with Internet Explorer 8. If you take a look at the company column in an example on [this page](http://examples1.ext.net/#/GridPanel/ArrayGrid/Simple/), It is cutting off the lines that are too long such as `E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Co...` *(just an example, not using a simple array grid; just a normal GridPanel)*

That is the correct behavior I would like, which is what happens in Firefox, and later versions of Internet Explorer.

However, in Internet Explorer 8 the row is actually wrapping to take up two rows, with the last bit in the second row.

I looked in documentation for 2.3, but not finding any config options that seem to help. I tried setting autoHeight to false, but no effect. Most other questions I find are the reverse, where they want it to wrap but it doesn't.

How can I keep Internet Explorer 8 from wrapping?

Here is the javascript...

**Column Model**

```
var columnModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
    {
        dataIndex: 'Name',
        id: 'fieldLabel',
        width: parseInt(width)/4
    },
    {
        dataIndex: 'Description',
        id: 'fieldDataGrey',
        width: parseInt(width)/4
    }
]);
```

**Grid Panel 1**

```
var Grid1 = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    id: 'Grid1',
    name: 'Grid1',
    store: DataStore1,
    cm: columnModel,
    width: parseInt(width)/2,
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: false,
    frame: false,
    stripeRows: false,
    columnLines: true,
    hideHeaders: true,
    enableColumnHide: false,
    disableSelection: true,
    overCls: '',
    loadMask: true
});
```

**Grid Panel 2**

```
var Grid2 = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    id: 'Grid2',
    name: 'Grid2',
    store: DataStore2,
    cm: columnModel,
    width: parseInt(width)/2,
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: false,
    frame: false,
    stripeRows: false,
    columnLines: true,
    hideHeaders: true,
    enableColumnHide: false,
    disableSelection: true,
    overCls: '',
    loadMask: true
});
```

**Field Set**

```
var FieldSet = new Ext.form.FieldSet({
    id: 'FieldSet',
    name: 'FieldSet',
    title: 'Title',
    border: true,
    width: width,
    autoHeight: false,
    labelWidth: 125,
    bodyStyle: 'padding:2px; margin:0px',
    style: 'padding:2px; margin:0px',
    layout: 'tableform',
    layoutConfig: {
        columns: 2,
        columnWidths:[.5, .5]
    },
    items: [
        Grid1,
        Grid2,
        {
            labelWidth: 125,
            layout: 'form',
            bodyStyle:'padding:2px 0px 0',
            items: Label,//Didn't include label with posted code
            colspan: 2
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further testing I did not find the solution I hoped for, but I did partially fix it by using a renderer rather than the `fieldDataGrey` id and using a column layout rather than the tableform layout.

Comment: It's not good to answer to self question here. You should write an answer in your primary post.

Comment: @Thevs I don't quite understand, _"It's not good to answer to self question here"_ 1. Why not? Your answer was valid so I upvoted, but not what I'm looking for - and I discovered a solution myself so shouldn't the question be closed? 2. Where is _here_ referring to?

Comment: Usually the answers to your post are added to comments of the question, or in the bottom of your question (marked as EDIT:).

Comment: @Thevs I think it is better to put one's own solution as an answer, rather than a comment or an edit. Advantage: A user that later searches is not interested who answered, but only if the answer is ok. Put an answer as an edit is not good, because the question will not be marked as solved.

Comment: But your answer is not a solution. It is a workaround.

Comment: @Thevs I think of a workaround as a type of solution. Regardless, I can always switch the accepted answer if a better one comes along; If Jimmy's answer gets some backing I can accept his instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use 2.2.1 ExtJs version, or 3.x. The problem I think lays in the Ext.js module in the Ext distribution, where browser versions are detected.

Comment: Thanks for the response, are there any ways around this other than upgrading my ExtJs version? For reasons beyond my control I cannot upgrade at this time.

Comment: You may look at the latest version and change Ext.js file according the new one manually.

Answer (score 2):

Ext.grid.ColumnModel has a config option called "renderer." I have used this function often for styling or DOM manipulation that Ext did not provide in the config options. You might try using the renderer function and returning an HTML string with custom styling that forces no wrapping on the data.

For instance,

```
renderer: function(value, metadata, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
    var style = 'overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap; width: 100px;',
        html = '<span style="' + style + '">' + value + '</span>';

    return html;
}
```

Where "width" (100px in this case) is the width you defined in your column.